# What are differences between OnCompleteListener and CompletionListener?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using realtime database and feel a little bit confuse between 2 methods below:

```
  ROOT_REF.updateChildren(map, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, @NonNull DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

            }
        });
```

```
        ROOT_REF.updateChildren(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

            }
        });
```

I want to know the differences between them and when should we use `CompletetionListener` or `OnCompleteListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While both `updateChildren()` methods do the same thing:

> Update the specific child keys to the specified values.

There is a difference between DatabaseReference's:

> [updateChildren(Map update)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#updateChildren(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E))

And

> [updateChildren(Map update, DatabaseReference.CompletionListener listener)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html)

Is that the first one returns a `Task<Void>` object and you can use [addOnCompleteListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#addOnCompleteListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener<TResult>)) to see when the work is done:

> Adds a listener that is called when the Task completes.

While the second one returns `void`. In order to update the children and see when the work is complete, you should pass as the second argument a `DatabaseReference.CompletionListener)` object, which basically is doing the same thing. Once you implement `onComplete()` method, you'll be notified when the work is complete on the particular reference.

You should use one or the other according with what you are more confortable with. I usually use the first one because in case I have more tasks that needs to be completed, I can use Tasks's [whenAllComplete(Task... tasks)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks.html#whenAllComplete(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E...)):

> Returns a Task with a list of Tasks that completes successfully when all of the specified Tasks complete.

And I see it's more convenient.